A particular planetary gearset

In the scheme there is a planetary gearset. I Know: Z1 = 102, Z2 = 11; Z3 = 13; Z4 = 19; Z5 = 152 and the angular velocity of gear 5 is 28 rad/s.
I use the typical reletion: $ \frac{\omega _{5} - \omega _{p}}{\omega _{1} - \omega _{p}} = \prod \tau _{i}=  \frac{Z_{1}}{Z_2}- \frac{Z_3}{Z_5}.  $
I think that $ \omega_1=0 $ (based on the picture) and also that the gear 4 could be a free gear.
I don't know what I have to think to put the correct sign (+ or -) when i divide the teeth number and also how to see if a gear is free.
I have to find $ \omega_p $.
Image source: me, i have copied it during a lesson.

I think you mean "geartrain", not "train gear" which suggests something railway related. Note that you need to credit the source of the image you have included in your post. It's site policy.

I clarified the question.
